# How does kernel know about physical pages are shared by two different processes?

Tags: c, linux, x86-64

We know that page tables are used to get the physical memory page address from the virtual memory page address. However, how the kernel knows about whether a physical memory page is shared by different processes (such as in case of a forked process and its parent process). Where is such list kept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kernel is the entity that creates all the virtual mappings. So it knows exactly what is shared and what is not. Userspace processes can't create shared mappings without help from the kernel.

The kernel is also responsible for duplicating the mappings when a process requests a fork. It has all the information required.

The number of mappings a page has is kept in a field in the `struct page` structure that represents that page. It is incremented each time a new mapping is created, and decremented when a mapping disappears.

If you want to dig deeper into this, you can visit [Linux-MM](http://linux-mm.org). Especially, read Mel Gorman's *[Understanding the Linux Virtual Memory Manager](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131453483)* book (very technical) linked (freely available PDF) in the Documentation section.

Comment: In case of forking (copy-on-write), how does the kernel knows that the original process is trying to write, so that it gives another physical page to it (copy-on-write)? Does it give read only access to the pages of original and forked process. So if original process modifies it, it gives a new physical page to it, but what if forked process later also modifies the page. How the kernel decides that it does not need to give a new physical page to it and can use the old one since now it is different from the original process.

Comment: Schematically, the pages that are initially shared by the two processes are marked read-only. When either process tries to write, which generates a fault, the kernel duplicates the page and updates the process's mappings. Both the freshly created page and the original one are set read/write, and no further actions are required on it. It  doesn't matter which if the parent or the child attempts a write first.

Comment: OK, I see. But when we say 'read-only', at MMU level, is it pertaining to a physical page or a virtual memory page?

Comment: Virtual address. (BTW, my previous comment is technically inexact, that's not exactly what happens in reality, see the linked book if you want the gory details.)

Answer (score 0):

cited from [CSAPP 3rd](https://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/), Linux kernel view of virtual memory for a process

[image]

> **pgd**, which points to the base of the level 1 page table (the page global directory), and mmap, which points to a list of vm_area_structs (area structs), each of which characterizes an area of the current virtual address space. When the kernel runs this process, it stores pgd in the CR3 control register.

- fvm_start. Points to the beginning of the area.
- vm_end. Points to the end of the area.
- vm_prot. Describes the read/write permissions for all of the pages contained in the area.
- **vm_flags**. Describes (among other things) whether the pages in the area are **shared** with other processes or private to this process.
- vm_next. Points to the next area struct in the list.

> When the **fork** function is called by the current process, the kernel creates various data structures for the new process and assigns it a unique PID. To create the virtual memory for the new process, it creates exact copies of the current process’s mm_struct, area structs, and page tables. It flags each page in both processes as read-only, and flags each area struct in both processes as **private copy- on-write.**

[image]